# bootbox with a ck_editor can't have access to special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, bootbox

I am using the `bootbox` with a ck_editor inside when I select the special characters from the tool bar the window is disable. I have this function that will do the replace and it display fine just can't can access to that window. Is there a event for the SpecialChar that I can get the focus?

```
function prepCkeditor() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['txtAddCompany'];
    if (!editor) {
        CKEDITOR.replace('txtAddCompany', {
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            height: 35,
            entities: false,
            contentsCss: 'body {overflow:hidden;font-family:"Raleway", "Open Sans", sans-serif; font-size: 14px;color:#555;}',
            resize_enabled: false,
            toolbar:
                [
                    { name: 'tools', items: ['SpecialChar', '-', 'Source', '-', 'Maximize'] }
                ]
        });
    } 
}
```

[image: Select special characters windows disable]

Comment: Your "special character" dialog isn't disabled, it just has a lower z-index than Bootstrap's modal uses.